# Universal data fetcher from similar entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have many similar EF5 entities for reference data. For example:

**ConsultationType entity**

```
public class ConsultationType
{
    public ConsultationType()
    {
        this.Appeals = new HashSet<Appeal>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Appeal> Appeals { get; set; }
}
```

**LawBranch entity**

```
public class LawBranch
{
    public LawBranch()
    {
        this.Appeals = new HashSet<Appeal>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Appeal> Appeals { get; set; }
}
```

**DbSet's in DB context**

```
public DbSet<LawBranch> LawBranches { get; set; }
public DbSet<ConsultationType> ConsultationTypes { get; set; }
```

As you see these entities have similar properties `Id` and `Title`.

**The actual problem**

I need a function that fetches data from database and puts it into list. Then the function inserts predefined object as a first element of this list.

My predefined object:

```
private class PredefinedReferenceItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public PredefinedReferenceItem()
    {
        this.Id = -1;
        this.Title = "some text";
    }
}
```

**My wrong solution:**

Firstly, I created interface `IReference` that describes reference entity

```
public interface IReference
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, my reference entities realize this interface

```
public class ConsultationType : IReference { ... }
public class LawBranch: IReference { ... }
```

Thirdly, I created the function

```
public IList<IReference> GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem<T>(DbSet<IReference> dbset)
{
    var data = from a in dbset
               orderby a.Title
               select a;

    var list = data.ToList();
    list.Insert(0, new PredefinedReferenceItem());

    return list;
}
```

But the function doesn't work in my viewmodel:

```
return GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem(dbContext.ConsultationTypes);
```

Error message in VS2012:

`The type arguments for method 'Mjc.Client.ViewModels.ViewModelBase.GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem<T>(System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Mjc.Foundation.IReference>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Please help me to find an error or specify the right direction.

Comment: There is one solution - simply create one base class for all reference entities, but it is not applicable for me, because I'm not sure that my reference classes will be 100% similar in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You new to change the GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem to use generics with IReference constraint on generic type T, the method should look like:

```
public IList<T> GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem<T>(DbSet<T> dbset) where T:IReference
{
    var data = from a in dbset
               orderby a.Title
               select a;

    var list = data.ToList();
    list.Insert(0, new PredefinedReferenceItem());

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[alexandr-mihalciuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236151/alexandr-mihalciuc) provided right solution. My addition to resolve type reference error:
**Final solution:**

```
public List<TEntity> GetReferenceWithPredefinedItem<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> dbset) where TEntity : class, new(), IReference
{
    var data = from a in dbset
               orderby a.Title
               select a;

    var list = data.ToList();
    list.Insert(0, new TEntity() { Id = -1, Title ="aefaef" });

    return list;
}
```